# finding the monthly covariance matrix given daily covariance matrix

Tags: programming, covariance-matrix

consider the following problem i am trying to find the monthly covariance matrix given daily data. i have the following codeimport datetime

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np

tickers = ['AAPL', 'AMZN', 'XOM']
start_date1 = datetime.date(2010, 1, 2)
end_date1 = datetime.date(2019, 12, 31)
daily_data1 = yf.download(tickers, start=start_date1, end=end_date1)  # definere datasættet
daily_data1 = daily_data1['Adj Close'].dropna()


frames = [v for _, v in daily_data1.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M'))]

for month in frames:
    cov_matrix = (month.pct_change().apply(lambda x: np.log(1 + x)).cov())
```

so i think i would multiply the cov_matrix with the length of the given month by i am unsure if its that easy so multiply the cov_matrix*len(month)? if someone could confirm it. Thanks in advance

Comment: IMO the best way to find the monthly covariance matrix is to downsample the daily data to monthly and then directly compute the covariance on that monthly data.

Comment: how do I do it. not sure what you mean. will remind you that the above is a part of a more extensive code where I am using daily data I have just deleted all unnecessary for my question

Comment: @Robert you can downsample your daily data to monthly, using one line of Python code: `daily_data1.resample('M').last()` will give you the last day of each month for the corresponding `daily_data1` dataframe. Now transform said monthly data to returns and compute the (rolling) covariance matrix on that data.

Comment: The nice part about @nbbo2 suggestion is that alignment and weak auto correlation  and cross correlation effects are less of a problem for monthly observations.  The daily alignment (perhaps of last trade) is less important for returns spanning a month. The effects of correlation are included in the monthly returns.

See also: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/71574/how-do-i-annualise-a-covariance-matrix